# concatenating arrays in python like matlab without knowing the size of the output array

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate arrays in python similar to matlab

```
array1= zeros(3,500);
array2=ones(3,700);
array=[array1, array2];
```

I did the following in python:

```
array1=np.zeros((3,500))
array2=np.ones((3,700))
array=numpy.concatenate((array1, array2), axis=2)
```

however this gives me different results when i access try to  "array[0,:]"
 is there a way in python to put arrays in one array similar to matlab.

Thank you

Comment: Note that your example code should have two pair of parentheses, like ``np.zeros((3,500))``

Comment: Uh, what code exactly are you using ? `axis=2` doesn't work, indices start from 0 in python. Otherwise it works fine for me, in both case I get one big row.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`concatenate((a,b),1)` or
`hstack((a,b))` or
`column_stack((a,b))` or
`c_[a,b]`

From here: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users)

Comment: this gives me return _nx.concatenate(arrays,1)
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Comment: ``np.concatenate((array1, array2), axis=1)`` works for me. What did you exactly try?