# Merge numpy arrays returned from loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a loop that generates numpy arrays:

```
for x in range(0, 1000):
   myArray = myFunction(x)
```

The returned array is always one dimensional. I want to combine all the arrays into one array (also one dimensional.

I tried the following, but it failed

```
allArrays = []
for x in range(0, 1000):
   myArray = myFunction(x)
   allArrays += myArray
```

The error is `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0) (9095)`. How can I get that to work?

For instance these two arrays:

```
[ 234 342 234 5454 34 6]
[ 23 2 1 4 55 34]
```

Shall be merge into this array:

```
[ 234 342 234 5454 34 6 23 2 1 4 55 34 ]
```

Comment: I want to concatenate them.

Comment: maybe concatenate((a,b),1) or hstack((a,b)) See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404077/concatenating-arrays-in-python-like-matlab-without-knowing-the-size-of-the-outpu

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably mean

```
allArrays = np.array([])
for x in range(0, 1000):
    myArray = myFunction(x)
    allArrays = np.concatenate([allArrays, myArray])
```

A more concise approach (see wims answer) is to use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions),

```
allArrays = np.concatenate([myFunction(x) for x in range])
```

Comment: If I use your first example. I get the error `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Comment: @ustroetz: Thanks for the catch, forgot the brackets as concatenate takes the arrays to be concatenated as a list.

Comment: It doesn't work, it says `all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 3 dimension(s)`

Comment: If you check the OP, this question and answer are for the case of 1-dimensional output arrays. It's clear from your comment that the output arrays you have are not always 1-dimensional (notice how the error message references a 3-dimensional array).

Answer (score 11):

You should know the shape of returned array. Suppose, myArray.shape = (2, 4)
Then

```
allArrays = np.empty((0, 4))
for x in range(0, 1000):
    myArray = myFunction(x)
    allArrays = np.append(allArrays, myArray, axis = 0)
```

Comment: doesnt this have the first row as the empty values?

Comment: no, because we create array with 0 rows and 4 columns: `array([], shape=(0, 4), dtype=float64)`

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you want to use [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
arrays = [myFunction(x) for x in range(1000)]
allArrays = np.concatenate(arrays)
```