# Concatenate numpy arrays in for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, numpy-ndarray

I've split an image up into 16 figures to plot regression and now I want to join it back together into one image.

I've written a for loop to do this but I'm having trouble understanding the advice from [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662996/merge-numpy-arrays-returned-from-loop) and where I'm going wrong. Please could someone explain why my input arrays do not have the same number of dimensions.

```
from scipy import interpolate


allArrays = np.array([])
for i in range(len(a)):

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.,0.,1.,1.])


    if np.amax(a[i]) > 0:
        x, y = np.where(a[i]>0)
        f = interpolate.interp1d(y, x)
        xnew = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), num=40)
        ynew = f(xnew)   
        plt.plot(xnew, ynew, '-')
        plt.ylim(256, 0)
        plt.xlim(0,256)

        fig.canvas.draw()
        X = np.array(fig.canvas.renderer._renderer)
        myArray = color.rgb2gray(X)
        print(myArray.shape)
        allArrays = np.concatenate([allArrays, myArray])
        print(allArrays.shape)

    else:

        plt.xlim(0,256)
        plt.ylim(0,256)
        fig.canvas.draw()
        X = np.array(fig.canvas.renderer._renderer)
        myArray = color.rgb2gray(X)
        print(myArray.shape)
        allArrays = np.concatenate([allArrays, myArray])
        print(allArrays.shape)




    i += 1
```

Output: myArray.shape (480, 640)

Error message: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

I'm sure it's really simple but I can't figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: What's the shape of `allArrays`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [226]: allArrays = np.array([])                                                   
In [227]: allArrays.shape                                                            
Out[227]: (0,)
In [228]: allArrays.ndim                                                             
Out[228]: 1

In [229]: myArray=np.ones((480,640))                                                 
In [230]: myArray.shape                                                              
Out[230]: (480, 640)
In [231]: myArray.ndim                                                               
Out[231]: 2
```

1 does not equal 2 in most worlds!

To concatenate with `myArray` on the default axis 0, `allArrays` would have to start as `np.zeros((0,640), myArray.dtype)`.  After `n` iterations it would grow to `(n*480, 640)`.

In the linked answer, the new arrays are all 1d, so starting with shape `(0,)` is ok.  But `wim's` answer is better - collect all arrays in a list, and do one concatenate at the end.

Repeated concatenate in a loop is hard to get right (you have to understand shapes and dimensions), and slower than list appends.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry that was really obvious! I used allArrays = np.delete(allArrays, slice(0,(len(myArray))), axis=0)
to remove the first numpy array after concatenation.